# 3 line long html preview text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a thread and want a little preview text for every thread. Like this:

```
How I can loose weight?  <- Headline
bla bla bla bla bla     |
bla bla bla bla bla     | <- Preview
bla bla bla bla bla...  |
```

I want there a three lines long preview text that end's simply with '...'
I tried it with:

```
.p {
color: grey; 
text-overflow: ellipsis; 
overflow: hidden; 
word-wrap: break-word; 
line-height: 16px; 
max-height: 32px;
}
```

but this haven't worked for me.. does anybody know a solution for that? maybe with JS or JQuery?

Comment: please share your html structure also

Comment: see https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/

Comment: `How I can loose weight?` http://www.health.com/health/gallery/0,,20501331,00.html

Comment: ellipsis like behavior on multi-line text requires JS.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar I'm just putting all that in a <p style="...."> bla bla </p> tag. I will take the code inside a class after I've got a solution.

Comment: Multi line truncating in CSS is surprisingly still not easily done in all major browsers. You might be interested in [this article](http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/)

Comment: @michaPau i tried it and it worked. but well, it's a dirty solution :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It works, see it here](https://jsfiddle.net/uzwtcmqj/1/)

```
.p {
  color: grey; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  white-space: nowrap; 
  line-height: 16px; 
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is kind of a dirty trick to make it fits on 3 lines with "..." content in the end :

```
.p {
  color: grey; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 16px; 
  position: relative;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.p:after { content: "..."; background: #f3f5f6; position :absolute; right: 0; bottom: 2px;}
```

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/uzwtcmqj/4/)

Comment: This will only ever be one line due to `white-space: nowrap` though

Comment: no it don't. thats just a single line. I want that preview to be 3 lines long and end with '...'

Comment: @Rory McCrossan You're right. I've updated my answer to make it fits on 3 lines.

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't give me the three dots at the end of the line..

Comment: The three dots are here because of this part :  `content: "...";`